# unwanted logout on page after form submitted

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, submit, action

i've make this form in bootstrap fw, but when i click on submit button, i'm logged from page.

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
...
...
some inputs
<div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
   <button id="mzBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default  onclick="doSomething()">My button</button>
</div>
</form>
```

I'm tried this js code but don't help it.

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by logged from page?

Comment: page is written in asp.net and after click im redirect to login page

Comment: remove the type="submit"  and add type="button" to the submit button.

Comment: yes, that remove my problem, but i lost ability submit form with enter button

Comment: remove your javascript that prevents default on form submit.